# log-transform all RHS terms

Tags: r, formula

I would like to log-transform each RHS variable in an R formula.

```r
f <- x ~ y
f1 <- update(f, . ~ . + z)
update(f, log(.) ~ log(.))
##  log(x) ~ log(y)
update(f1, log(.) ~ log(.))
##  log(x) ~ log(y + z)
```

What I *really* want is `log(x) ~ log(y) + log(z)`.

Comment: You might use the identity `log(y*z)=log(y)+log(z)`

Comment: `f = x ~ yz` and `update(f, log(.) ~ log(.))` but you want to keep your `f` definition?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is write a convenience wrapper; the underlying function terms need to be log-transformed, but I don't want the user to think too hard about it.

Comment: I assume you also want the transformation to be mathematically correct...

Comment: @RHertel, yes, that would be ideal...

Comment: Well, for starters `log(y+z)` is not equal to `log(y)+log(z)`. So if you want to end up with a term `log(y)+log(z)` on the RHS, I suggest that you use the identity that I noted above and proceed as described by @ColonelBeauvel

Comment: I'm aware that `log(y+z) != log(y) + log(z)`; hence my question. I think that this solution is unsatisfactory as it requires the user to know that the formula will be log-transformed, and use multiply operations instead of addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps transform to "character", insert "log", and then back to "formula":

```
> f <- x ~ y

> f1 <- update(f, . ~ . + z)

> a <- sapply(all.vars(f1),function(x){sprintf("log(%s)",x)})

> f2 <- as.formula(paste(a[1],paste(a[-1],collapse="+"),sep="~"))
> f
x ~ y
> f1
x ~ y + z
> f2
log(x) ~ log(y) + log(z)
>
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work if the RHS contains already a function:

```
> f1 <- update(f, . ~ . + z + exp(v))

> a <- sapply(all.vars(f1),function(x){sprintf("log(%s)",x)})

> f2 <- as.formula(paste(a[1],paste(a[-1],collapse="+"),sep="~"))
> f1
x ~ y + z + exp(v)
> f2
log(x) ~ log(y) + log(z) + log(v)
>
```

But this works:

```
f1 <- update(x ~ y, . ~ . + z + exp(v))
a <- strsplit(as.character(f1),"\\+|~")
b <- sapply(a,function(x){sprintf("log(%s)",x)})
f2 <- as.formula(paste(b[1],paste(b[-1],collapse="+"),sep="~"))
##  log(x) ~ log(y) + log(z) + log(exp(v))
```